# Scikit SVM gives very poor accuracy for STL-10 dataset

Tags: scikit-learn, svm, scikit-image

I am using Scikit-learn SVM for training my model for STL-10 dataset which contains 5000 training images (10 pre-defined folds). So I have 5000*96*96*3 size dataset for training and test purposes. I used following code to train it and measure the accuracy for the test set. (80% 20%). Final result was 0.323 accuracy. How can I increase the accuracy for SVM.

This is [STL10 dataset](https://cs.stanford.edu/~acoates/stl10/)

```
def train_and_evaluate(clf, train_x, train_y):
    clf.fit(train_x, train_y)

#make 2D array as we can apply only 2d to fit() function
nsamples, nx, ny, nz = images.shape
reshaped_train_dataset = images.reshape((nsamples, nx * ny * nz))

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(reshaped_train_dataset, read_labels(LABEL_PATH), test_size=0.20, random_state=33)

train_and_evaluate(my_svc, X_train, Y_train)

print(metrics.accuracy_score(Y_test, clf2.predict(X_test)))
```

Comment: _How can I increase the accuracy for SVM?_

Feature Engineering probably, and experimenting with different kernels, but you can also give more detail about your dataset.

Comment: I think the problem is with reshaping my data into (5000, 27648) dataset from (5000*96*96*3). Updated the question with the link of the dataset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it seems you are using raw SVM directly on the images. That is usually not a good idea (it is rather bad actually).

I will describe the classic image-classification pipeline popular in the last decades! Keep in mind, that the highest performing approaches *right now* might use Deep Neural Networks to combine some of these steps (a very different approach; a lot of research in the last years!)

- **First step**:

  - **Preprocessing** is needed!

    - **Normalize** mean and variance (i would not expect your dataset to be already normalized)
    - Optional: **histogram-equalization**
- **Second step**:

  - **Feature-extraction** -> you should learn some features from these images. There are a lot of approaches including

    - **(Kernel-)PCA**
    - **(Kernel-)LDA**
    - **Dictionary-learning**
    - **Matrix-factorization**
    - **Local binary patterns**
    - ... (just test with LDA initially)
- **Third**:

  - **SVM** for classification

    - again there might be a Normalization-step needed before this and as mentioned in the comments by @David Batista: there might be some parameter-tuning needed (especially for Kernel-SVM)

It is also not clear, if using color-information is wise here. For more simple approaches i expect black-and-white images to be superior (you are losing information but tuning your pipeline is more robust; high-performance approaches will of course use color-information).

See [here](http://blog.yhat.com/posts/image-classification-in-Python.html) for some random tutorial describing a similar problem. While i don't know if it's good work, you could immediatly recognize the processing-pipeline mentioned above (preprocessing, feature-extraction, classifier-learning)!

**Edit:**
Why preprocessing?: some algorithms assume centered samples with unit-variance, therefore normalization is needed. This is (at least) very important for PCA, LDA and SVM's.